# Bus error when reading register using mmap

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I developed a kernel module which allocates some kernel memory and remaps it to physical registers of an FPGA when user software opens the device, it also writes in a hardware register which triggers an interruption which is finally used by the probing functions of the kernel to detect the IRQ number at module init, which is 61 in my case. (I got to this point reading the excellent LDD3 book from O'Reilly, but since I'm a newbie in the kernel world I have some trouble getting my driver working well)

Thereby, I am accessing hardware registers from the kernel itself and from the user space using a small soft that I named "regedit". To access the registers from the kernel I used ioremap and I wrote the mmap function to allow regedit to access the registers from the user space using remap_pfn_range.

My first problem is that I suppose there is a better way than separately calling ioremap and remap_pfn_range to do the same thing, but I don't know how to allocate memory, remap it, access it from the kernel and by the same time provide it to the user space.

My second problem is that when I install the module, I see that my driver is able to read and write the registers using ioremap because I successfully detect the IRQ number by triggering an interrupt (by writing the register at offset 0), and when opening the device, my irq handler routine is called and successfully acknowledges the interrupt by writing 0 in the register. But, because there is a but, when I try to read the same register using my soft regedit, I get a bus error.

My guess is that only three registers are physically wired (offsets 0, 4 and 8) and maybe when I think I'm reading a single 32 bits register, the kernel is in fact reading a larger buffer (PAGE_SIZE aligned I presume) and accesses a forbidden area. (To prove that the problem is from my driver I used /dev/mem in my regedit soft, and it's working fine)

I am using a linux kernel 3.12 on a Xilinx Zynq ZC702 board using a processor ARM Cortex A9.

Here is the code of my driver :

### **Driver Header File**

```
#ifndef DRIVER_H_
#define DRIVER_H_

/* --------------------------------------------------------------
 *              External References
 * ------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>

/* --------------------------------------------------------------
 *              Application Includes
 * ------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* --------------------------------------------------------------
 *              Constants Definition
 * ------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define MODULE_NAME             "mydriver"
#define DEFAULT_MAJOR_NUMBER    0           // If zero, major number will be automatically allocated
#define DEFAULT_MINOR_NUMBER    0
#define NB_DEVICES              1           // Number of devices to register

/*
 * Hardware defines
 */
#define NB_PAGES                256        // Number of pages of the memory mapping
#define REG_IRQ                 0x43C00000 // IRQ register address

/*
 * Modules params
 */
static unsigned int irq_param = 0;

/*
 * Kernel module information
 */
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("AwaX");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
MODULE_ALIAS(MODULE_NAME);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Kernel module which handles the hardware interrupts and process them");

module_param(irq_param, int, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(irq_param, "The IRQ line number to be used");

/* --------------------------------------------------------------
 *              Macros Definition
 * ------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define LOG(kernLvl, str, tag)      printk(kernLvl "%-6.6s %s() : "str"\n", tag, (char*) __func__);
#define LOGA(kernLvl, str, tag,...) printk(kernLvl "%-6.6s %s() : "str"\n", tag, (char*) __func__, __VA_ARGS__);

#define LOG_TRACE(str) LOG(KERN_DEBUG, str, "KTRACE")
#define LOG_DEBUG(str) LOG(KERN_INFO, str, "KDEBUG")
#define LOG_INFO(str)  LOG(KERN_NOTICE, str, "KINFO")
#define LOG_IT(str)    LOG(KERN_NOTICE, str, "IT")
#define LOG_WARN(str)  LOG(KERN_WARNING, str, "KWARN")
#define LOG_ERROR(str) LOG(KERN_ERR, str, "KERROR")
#define LOG_FATAL(str) LOG(KERN_ALERT, str, "KFATAL")

#define LOG_TRACE_(str,...) LOGA(KERN_DEBUG, str, "KTRACE", __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_DEBUG_(str,...) LOGA(KERN_INFO, str, "KDEBUG", __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_INFO_(str,...)  LOGA(KERN_NOTICE, str, "KINFO", __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_IT_(str,...)        LOGA(KERN_NOTICE, str, "IT", __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_WARN_(str,...)  LOGA(KERN_WARNING, str, "KWARN", __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_ERROR_(str,...) LOGA(KERN_ERR, str, "KERROR", __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_FATAL_(str,...) LOGA(KERN_ALERT, str, "KFATAL", __VA_ARGS__)

/* --------------------------------------------------------------
 *              Types Definition
 * ------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*
 * Internal data structure
 */
typedef struct _module_data {
    int major;              // Major device number
    int minor;              // Minor device number
    dev_t mmap_dev;         // Holds device numbers (major and minor)
    struct cdev mmap_cdev;  // Kernel internal struct representing the device

    int  *vmalloc_area;     // Pointer to the vmalloc'd area - always page aligned
    int  *kmalloc_area;     // Pointer to the kmalloc'd area, rounded up to a page boundary
    void *kmalloc_ptr;      // Original pointer for kmalloc'd area as returned by kmalloc

    // Mapping
    volatile int  *map_area; // Base address of the registers kernel memory
    volatile void *io_area;  // Base address of the registers i/o physical memory

    // Interrupts
    unsigned int irq; // Interrupt number
} module_data;

/* --------------------------------------------------------------
 *              Functions Definition
 * ------------------------------------------------------------*/

#endif /* DRIVER_H_ */
```

### **Driver Source File**

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------------
 *              External References
 * ------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include "driver.h"

#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/memory.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/io.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <asm-generic/errno-base.h>

/* --------------------------------------------------------------
 *              Application Includes
 * ------------------------------------------------------------*/


/* --------------------------------------------------------------
 *              Static data
 * ------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Internal data
static module_data *_module;

/* --------------------------------------------------------------
 *              Local Functions Definition
 * ------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*
 * Module functions
 */
static int  __init  my_module_init     (void);
static void __exit  my_module_cleanup  (void);
static int          my_module_open     (struct inode *inode, struct file *filp);
static int          my_module_release  (struct inode *inode, struct file *filp);
static int          my_module_mmap     (struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma);

/*
 * Static functions
 */
static void         my_vma_open        (struct vm_area_struct *vma);
static void         my_vma_close       (struct vm_area_struct *vma);
static irqreturn_t  my_irq_handler     (int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs);
static int          my_allocate_device (void);
static int          my_register_device (void);
static unsigned int my_probe_irq       (void);
static int          my_mmap_kmem       (struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma);
static int          my_mmap_vmem       (struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma);

/*
 * Specifies the functions associated with the device operations.
 */
static struct file_operations _module_fops = {
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .open = my_module_open,
        .release = my_module_release,
        .mmap = my_module_mmap,
};

/*
 * Specifies the functions associated with the remap operations.
 */
static struct vm_operations_struct _module_vmops = {
        .open = my_vma_open,
        .close = my_vma_close,
};

/* --------------------------------------------------------------
 *              Functions Implementation
 * ------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*****************************************************************************
 * Initialization function of the module which allocates the major and minor
 * numbers and registers the device to /proc/devices. The creation of the
 * device in /dev must be done by an external script.
 *
 * @return
 *      SUCCESS : 0
 *      FAILURE : Negative error code.
 *****************************************************************************/
static int __init my_module_init (void) {
    unsigned int irqprobe = 0;
    int err = 0;
    int i = 0;

    LOG_INFO_("Initializing module %s", MODULE_NAME);
    LOG_INFO_("Module param : irq_param = %u", irq_param);

    /*
     * Init internal data
     */
    _module = kmalloc(sizeof(module_data), GFP_KERNEL);
    memset(_module, 0, sizeof(module_data));
    if (_module == NULL) {
        goto out;
    }
    _module->major = DEFAULT_MAJOR_NUMBER;
    _module->minor = DEFAULT_MINOR_NUMBER;
    _module->map_area = NULL;
    _module->io_area  = NULL;
    _module->irq = irq_param;

    /*
     * Allocate kmalloc memory
     */
    _module->kmalloc_ptr = kmalloc((NB_PAGES + 2) * PAGE_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (_module->kmalloc_ptr == NULL) {
        err = -ENOMEM;
        goto out_kfree;
    }
    // Round it up to the page bondary
    _module->kmalloc_area = (int *) ((((unsigned long) _module->kmalloc_ptr) + PAGE_SIZE - 1) & PAGE_MASK);

    // Use the kernel memory to access registers from the module
    _module->map_area = _module->kmalloc_area;

    /*
     * Allocate vmalloc memory
     */
    _module->vmalloc_area = (int *) vmalloc(NB_PAGES * PAGE_SIZE);
    if (_module->vmalloc_area == NULL) {
        err = -ENOMEM;
        goto out_vfree;
    }

    /*
     * Remap physical addresses
     */
    _module->io_area = ioremap(REG_IRQ, NB_PAGES * PAGE_SIZE);
    if (_module->io_area == NULL) {
        LOG_ERROR_("Physical memory remapping failed (base_addr=%#x, size=%#lx)", REG_IRQ, NB_PAGES * PAGE_SIZE);
        goto out_iofree;
    }

    /*
     * Allocates the device numbers
     */
    err = my_allocate_device();
    if (err) {
        LOG_ERROR_("Device allocation failed with code : %d", err);
        goto out_unalloc_region;
    }

    // If no IRQ number has been specified
    if (_module->irq <= 0) {
        // Probes for an IRQ line number
        LOG_INFO("Probing IRQ number...");
        irqprobe = my_probe_irq();
        if (irqprobe == 0) { // Probe failed
            LOG_ERROR("IRQ probing failed : cannot find IRQ number");
        } else if (irqprobe < 0) { // Probe error
            LOG_ERROR_("IRQ probing failed with error code : %d", err);
        } else {
            // If an irq number is found
            LOG_INFO_("IRQ number detected : %u", irqprobe);
            _module->irq = irqprobe;
        }
    } else { // If an irq number has been specified via a module parameter
        LOG_INFO_("IRQ number param specified : irq=%u", _module->irq);
    }

    // Registers the device making it live immediately
    err = my_register_device();
    if (err) {
        LOG_ERROR_("Device register failed with code : %d", err);
        goto out_unregister;
    }

    LOG_INFO_("Module %s initialized successfully !", MODULE_NAME);
    return 0;

    /*
     * Error fallbacks
     */
    out_unregister:
        LOG_DEBUG_("Deallocating chrdev for %s", MODULE_NAME);
        cdev_del(&_module->mmap_cdev);
        // Unreserve the pages
        LOG_DEBUG("Unreserving memory pages");
        for (i = 0; i < NB_PAGES * PAGE_SIZE; i += PAGE_SIZE) {
            SetPageReserved(vmalloc_to_page((void *) (((unsigned long) _module->vmalloc_area) + i)));
            SetPageReserved(virt_to_page(((unsigned long )_module->kmalloc_area) + i));
        }
    out_unalloc_region:
        LOG_DEBUG_("Unregistering device %s", MODULE_NAME);
        unregister_chrdev_region(_module->mmap_dev, NB_DEVICES);
    out_iofree:
        iounmap(_module->io_area);
    out_vfree:
        vfree(_module->vmalloc_area);
    out_kfree:
        kfree(_module->kmalloc_ptr);
    out:
    return err;
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * Cleanup function of the module which unregisters the major number and
 * removes the created device from the system.
 *
 * @return
 *      void
 *****************************************************************************/
static void __exit my_module_cleanup (void) {
    LOG_INFO_("Cleaning up module %s", MODULE_NAME);

    // Unregisters a range of device numbers.
    unregister_chrdev_region(_module->mmap_dev, NB_DEVICES);
    LOG_INFO_("Unregistered device %s", MODULE_NAME);

    // Free kernel memory
    vfree(_module->vmalloc_area);
    kfree(_module->kmalloc_ptr);
    kfree(_module);

    // Remove the cdev from the system, possibly freeing the structure itself
    cdev_del(&_module->mmap_cdev);
    LOG_INFO_("Deallocated chrdev for %s", MODULE_NAME);
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * Open function of the module which makes this module accessible from the
 * user space.
 *
 * @return
 *      SUCCESS : 0
 *      FAILURE : Negative error code.
 *****************************************************************************/
static int my_module_open (struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
    int err = 0;

    // If an interrupt line has been requested
    if (_module->irq > 0) {
        // Registers the interrupt handler to the kernel
        err = request_irq(_module->irq, (irq_handler_t) my_irq_handler, 0, MODULE_NAME, _module);
        if (err) {
            LOG_ERROR_("%s : Cannot get assigned irq %d, request_irq() failed, code=%d", MODULE_NAME, _module->irq, err);
            _module->irq = -1;
            return err;
        } else {
            LOG_INFO_("IRQ number %u assigned successfully to module %s", _module->irq, MODULE_NAME);
        }
    } else {
        LOG_ERROR("Invalid IRQ number : the device will not see the hardware interrupts");
    }
    LOG_INFO_("%s opened successfully", MODULE_NAME);
    return 0;
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * Close function of the module which releases the use of this module from
 * the user space.
 *
 * @return
 *      SUCCESS : 0
 *      FAILURE : Negative error code.
 *****************************************************************************/
static int my_module_release (struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
    LOG_INFO_("%s closing...", MODULE_NAME);
    // Removes the interrupt handler from kernel
    LOG_INFO_("Releasing irq number %u", _module->irq);
    free_irq(_module->irq, _module);
    LOG_INFO_("%s closed", MODULE_NAME);
    return 0;
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * Creates a new mapping in the virtual address space of the calling process.
 * It makes possible for a user process to access physical memory in the
 * kernel space.
 *
 * @param   filp
 *              The file or device.
 * @param   vma
 *              The virtual memory area into which the page range is being
 *              mapped.
 * @return
 *      SUCCESS : 0
 *      FAILURE : Negative error code.
 *****************************************************************************/
static int my_module_mmap (struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma) {
    unsigned long start     = vma->vm_start;        // Virtual address where remapping begins
    unsigned long end       = vma->vm_end;
    unsigned long length    = end - start;
    unsigned long maxLength = NB_PAGES * PAGE_SIZE;
    unsigned long pgoff     = vma->vm_pgoff;        // PFN of the physAddr to which vAddr is mapped

    // Checks length - do not allow larger mappings than the number of pages allocated
    if (length > maxLength) {
        LOG_ERROR_("Specified virtual memory area is too big : 0x%lx , 0x%lx", length, maxLength);
        return -EIO;
    }

    // At offset 0
    if (pgoff == 0) {
        // we map the vmalloc'd area
        LOG_DEBUG_("Allocating virtual memory, start=%#lx, length=%#lx, pgoff=%#lx", start, length, pgoff);
        return my_mmap_vmem(filp, vma);
    } else {
        // we map the kmalloc'd area
        LOG_DEBUG_("Allocating kernel memory, start=%#lx, length=%#lx, pgoff=%#lx", start, length, pgoff);
        return my_mmap_kmem(filp, vma);
    }
    return -EIO;
}

static void my_vma_open (struct vm_area_struct* vma) {
    LOG_INFO_("%s VMA open, virtAddr=%#lx, physAddr=%#lx", MODULE_NAME, vma->vm_start, vma->vm_pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT);
}

static void my_vma_close (struct vm_area_struct* vma) {
    LOG_INFO_("%s VMA close", MODULE_NAME);
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * Interrupt handler which :
 *      - Reads the registers to know the source of the IT,
 *      - Clears the IT and wakes up the handler task.
 *
 * @param irq
 *              The interrupt number requested.
 * @param dev_id
 *              Pointer to the device structure passed to the function
 *              request_irq() containing internal data (used when the driver
 *              manages several instances of the same device).
 * @param regs
 *              Used for debug. Holds a snapshot of the processor's context
 *              before the processor entered interrupted code.
 * @return
 *      SUCCESS : 0
 *      FAILURE : Negative error code.
 *****************************************************************************/
static irqreturn_t my_irq_handler (int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs) {
    module_data *moduleData = dev_id;
    LOG_IT_("%s interrupted, interrupt number = %d", MODULE_NAME, irq);
    if (moduleData != NULL) {
        // Resets irq
        iowrite32(0x0, _module->io_area);
        wmb();
    } else {
        LOG_ERROR("Device structure is NULL");
    }
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * Allocates major and minor numbers for this device.
 *
 * @return
 *      SUCCESS : 0
 *      FAILURE : Negative error code.
 *****************************************************************************/
static int my_allocate_device (void) {
    int err = 0;

    // If a non zero major number is specified
    if (_module->major) {
        // Updates the dev structure used as input for register_chrdev_region
        _module->mmap_dev = MKDEV(_module->major, _module->minor);
        // Registers a range of device numbers.
        err = register_chrdev_region(_module->mmap_dev, NB_DEVICES, MODULE_NAME);
    } else { // If major number is zero, then allocates it dynamically
        // Allocates a range of char device numbers chosen dynamically
        err = alloc_chrdev_region(&_module->mmap_dev, _module->minor, NB_DEVICES, MODULE_NAME);
        _module->major = MAJOR(_module->mmap_dev);
    }
    // Checks result
    if (err) {
        LOG_ERROR_("cannot get major number %d", _module->major);
        return err;
    } else {
        LOG_INFO_("Registered device %s : major=%d, minor=%d", MODULE_NAME, _module->major, _module->minor);
    }

    // Initializes cdev and file operations
    cdev_init(&_module->mmap_cdev, &_module_fops);
    _module->mmap_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    _module->mmap_cdev.ops = &_module_fops;

    return 0;
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * Registers the device, makes it live immediately, therefore all
 * initialization routines must be done before calling this function.
 *
 * @return
 *      SUCCESS : 0
 *      FAILURE : Negative error code.
 *****************************************************************************/
static int my_register_device (void) {
    int err = 0;

    // Adds the device to the system making it live immediately
    err = cdev_add(&_module->mmap_cdev, _module->mmap_dev, NB_DEVICES);
    if (err) {
        LOG_ERROR("Could not allocate chrdev");
        return err;
    } else {
        LOG_INFO_("Allocated chrdev for %s", MODULE_NAME);
    }
    return 0;
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * This function uses the probe functions of the kernel to find the irq
 * number of the hardware device.
 *
 * @return
 *      SUCCESS : 0
 *      FAILURE : Negative error code.
 *****************************************************************************/
static unsigned int my_probe_irq (void) {
    unsigned int irq = -1;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        volatile unsigned long mask;

        // Reset the interrupts
        iowrite32(0x0, _module->io_area);
        wmb(); // Memory barrier

        // Start kernel probing
        mask = probe_irq_on();

        // Trigger all interrupts
        iowrite32(0xffffffff, _module->io_area);
        wmb(); // Memory barrier

        // Wait for it
        ndelay(1000);

        // Try to find which interrupt occurred
        irq = probe_irq_off(mask);
    } while (irq < 0 && count++ < 5);
    return irq;
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * Helper function, mmap's the vmalloc'd area which is not physically
 * contiguous.
 *
 * @return
 *      SUCCESS : 0
 *      FAILURE : Negative error code.
 *****************************************************************************/
static int my_mmap_vmem (struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma) {
    unsigned long start = vma->vm_start;
    unsigned long end   = vma->vm_end;
    unsigned long pfn   = 0;
    long length         = end - start;
    int ret = 0;

    // Check length - do not allow larger mappings than the number of pages allocated
    if (length > NB_PAGES * PAGE_SIZE) {
        LOG_ERROR_("Specified length (%lu) is larger than the number of pages allocated", length);
        return -EIO;
    }

    // Loop over all pages, map it page individually
    while (length > 0) {
        pfn = vmalloc_to_pfn(_module->vmalloc_area);
        ret = remap_pfn_range(vma, start, pfn, PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_SHARED);
        if (ret < 0) {
            LOG_ERROR_("remap_pfn_range() failed with error %d, addr=%#lx, offset=%#lx", ret, start, pfn);
            return ret;
        }
        start += PAGE_SIZE;
        _module->vmalloc_area += PAGE_SIZE;
        length -= PAGE_SIZE;
    }
    vma->vm_ops = &_module_vmops; // Specifies open_vma() and close_vma() functions
    my_vma_open(vma); // Calls explicitely open_vma() as its not done by calling mmap()
    return 0;
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * Helper function, mmap's the kmalloc'd area which is physically contiguous.
 *
 * @return
 *      SUCCESS : 0
 *      FAILURE : Negative error code.
 *****************************************************************************/
static int my_mmap_kmem (struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma) {
    unsigned long start = vma->vm_start;
    unsigned long end   = vma->vm_end;
    long length         = end - start;
    int ret = 0;

    // Check length - do not allow larger mappings than the number of pages allocated
    if (length > NB_PAGES * PAGE_SIZE) {
        LOG_ERROR_("Specified length (%lu) is larger than the number of pages allocated", length);
        return -EIO;
    }

    // Map the whole physically contiguous area in one piece
    //pfn = virt_to_phys((void *) _module->kmalloc_area) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
    ret = remap_pfn_range(vma, start, vma->vm_pgoff, length, vma->vm_page_prot);
    if (ret < 0) {
        return ret;
    }
    vma->vm_ops = &_module_vmops; // Specifies open_vma() and close_vma() functions
    my_vma_open(vma); // Calls explicitely open_vma() as its not done by calling mmap()
    return 0;
}

/*
 * MANDATORY
 *
 * Used by kernel to load this module and specifies its entry points.
 */
module_init(my_module_init);
module_exit(my_module_cleanup);
```

Comment: What `prot` and `flags` you use in regedit `mmap()`?

Comment: I used : mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)

Comment: `SIGBUS` means the address was valid, but not allowed; I was hoping it was just incorrect `prot` in regedit. It is OK. Please see [these slides](http://www.makelinux.net/books/embedded_linux_kernel_and_drivers/img147) to ensure you understand the central logic with memory mapping. That said, I think you should replace `kmalloc()`/`vmalloc()`/`remap_pfn_range()` with [`vm_iomap_memory()`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-vm-iomap-memory.html).

Comment: I have some news : I disabled the bus error generation in the FPGA when user reads/writes a non-existing address and the driver is working... But I can't trigger interrupt by writing in the associated FPGA register, it's like my data are cached somewhere...

Comment: (...) That said, I don't know why I got a bus error before disabling the bus error flag because I was all the time writing to an existing address. Is it possible that the kernel is in fact reading a larger memory block ? And by disabling the bus error flag generation, I'm in fact silently reading a non existing memory block ?

Comment: No, the kernel does not intervene when you read from or write to the memory map. It just sets up the "window". That said, I think the problem lies in how you set up the virtual memory "window", and that is causing the issues. The IOMMU (hardware that manages the mapping) can do e.g. write combining, and it is possible the error is related. Compare to e.g. [zynq-xdma](https://github.com/bmartini/zynq-xdma/blob/master/dev/xdma.c#L68) and [roach2](https://github.com/ska-sa/roach2_linux/blob/master/drivers/char/roach2/roach2_fpga.c#L522), which explicitly disable caching.